# Git Like Software

Tags: mysql, git, unix

I am really thinking of how I can build a very minimal Git-like software only for my self for now!

I have gone through Git documentations and even the way git works and I have quite an understanding on it.

Is there any example for me to study as a bonus before I dive into this project?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the [`Documentation/technical`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/technical) folder which explains the internals of Git, you can study how Git was re-implemented, as an exercice, in other languages.

See for instance:

- in Go the project [`src-d/go-git`](https://github.com/src-d/go-git) (recent 2018),
- in Javascript: [`danlucraft/git.js`](https://github.com/danlucraft/git.js) (much older),
- In Javascript (more recent 2015): [Gitlet](http://gitlet.maryrosecook.com/).
- In Java, the project [`eclipse/jgit`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit) (used by [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/))
- In C (with a lot of bindings for other languages), [LibGit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) (and its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2), apologies to [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) for not mentioning it first.)

Comment: Thank you @VonC I really appreciate, and by the way I think I will just clone  danlucraft/git.js for now and get familiar the code to see if I can make something out of it. Thank you.

Comment: in addition, jgit could be useful https://github.com/eclipse/jgit

Comment: @pedrorijo91 Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: You forgot also this project also https://libgit2.github.com/

Comment: @Philippe Thank you. I cannot believe I forgot about libgit2! Edward (https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) would not be pleased ;)

Comment: @VonC I have gone through libgit2 and it sound relating to what I might be talking about, but the fact is that I don't know how best to accomplish my task, if i'm permitted, here is what I want to achieve, I am building a site already using laravel framework, and the idea is to integrate it with a version control system, as minimal as possible! just to make sharing of code possible between the site users alone, so I guess I might be looking into hosting codes or related just like github. I apologies if my question is becoming extensive, just need help.

Comment: @W.Seun Why not installaing git itself?

Comment: @VonC and where will my codes be saved if I may ask?

Comment: @W.Seun A bit like https://blog.runcloud.io/2017/01/15/laravel-with-git-deployment-the-right-way.html or http://blog.netgloo.com/2016/01/28/deploying-a-laravel-application-on-sitegrounds-shared-hosting-with-git/

Comment: @VonC Thank you for the informations.